# Matching multicharacter strings without saving the match in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In PHP using preg_match I want to match one of many multicharacter strings (e.g. "date", "after" and "latest") (followed by some more match, which are saved e.g. ([0-9]+) and the like ).

If it were a single characters (e.g. b, f and g) the regexp would just be:

```
 /[bfg] rest of the regex(p)?/
```

If I were to match (and save) the match of multicharacter strings it would be something like:

```
 /(date|after|latest) rest of the regex(p)?/
```

Now can I match "date", "after" or "latest" without saving whichever one was matched in the resulting array?

Comment: M42's answer is correct. If you don't need to capture the "p" then you should change `regex(p)?` to `regexp?`. I know it isn't related to your question, but I thought I'd add it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use non capture group:

```
 /(?:date|after|latest) rest of the regex(p)?/
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `?:` suppresses capturing _content between parentheses_ into a back reference.